# onchage event delegation to append textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code where everytime i hit "btn_add" i get 3 new textfields (usd_value, pesos_value and percent )...i want to add a change event to all usd_value texts so when they change, pesos_value of all items change their values for =usd_value * percent.Im tryiing to do the delegation at the end of code but it's not working :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js" charset="UTF-8" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var obj = $('input[name="percent"]').length;

            var n = 0;

            $('#btn_add').click(function(){
                n++;
                $('table').append('<tr id="btn_minus'+n+'"><td><input type="text" name="cost_element" value="0" readonly/></td><td><input type="text" name="description" value="{{cost_element.description}}"/></td><td><input type="text" id="id_usd_value" name="usd_value" value="{{cost_element.usd_value}}"/></td><td><input type="text" id="id_pesos_value" name="pesos_value" value="{{cost_element.pesos_value}}"/></td><td><input type="text" size= 3 id="id_rer_value" name="percent" value="{{cost_element.percent}}"/>%</td><td><input class="btn_minus btn btn-danger" name="btn_minus'+n+'" type="button" value="X"/></td></tr>');

                obj = $('input[name="percent"]').length;
            });

            $('table').on('click',".btn_minus",function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('name');
                $('tr[id="'+id+'"]').remove();
            });

            $('.btn_delete').click(function(){
                location.href = "";
            });

            setInterval(function(){
                var percents = new Array();

                $('input[name="percent"]').each(function() {
                    percents.push($(this).val());
                });

                var sum = 0;
                for(var i=0, l=percents.length; i<l; i++) {
                    sum = sum + parseInt(percents[i],10);
                }

                $('#msgValidar').empty();
                if(sum == 100){
                        $('#msgValidar').append('<h5 style="color: blue">Los valores de procentaje estan correctos.</h5>');
                        $('#btn_ok').removeClass('disabled');
                }else{
                    if(obj != 0){
                        $('#msgValidar').append('<h5 style="color: red">Los valores de procentaje deben sumar exactamente 100%.</h5>');
                        $('#btn_ok').addClass('disabled');
                    }
                }
            }, 500);

            $('table').on('change','.usd_value',function(){
                alert('work!');

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Can you help me ?? Thanks !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: If you check my code, you'll see that's exactly what im trying to do based on that post accepted answer but it doesn't work

Comment: The delegation code should occur on page load, not on button click.  Or you'll end up binding the events more than once.

Comment: Sorry, i miss it here, but it's ok in code. What can i do ?

Comment: Move the other `.on` calls outside `$('#btn_add').click(function(){ ... }`

Comment: They're already outside, as independent functions

Comment: No, they are clearly inside the click event being applied to `#btn_add`, I can see the curly braces.  Unless your code is out of date, or your intentation is misaligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code. First of all, you can't add dinamically more object with the same ID, and then refer to the objects by ID, the ID must be unique. You closed wrong the parenthesis too. And the change event is not wrong, but in your "append", you isn't setted the class, but "name" and "ID" TAG, and the reference ".usd_value" is a class selector...

Try this, but you must correct the rest of your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var n = 0;

    $('#btn_add').click(function() {
      n++;
      $('table').append('<tr id="btn_minus' + n + '"><td><input type="text" name="cost_element" value="0" readonly/></td><td><input type="text" name="description" value="{{cost_element.description}}"/></td><td><input type="text" id="id_usd_value" name="usd_value" class="usd_value" value="{{cost_element.usd_value}}"/></td><td><input type="text" id="id_pesos_value" name="pesos_value" value="{{cost_element.pesos_value}}"/></td><td><input type="text" size= 3 id="id_rer_value" name="percent" value="{{cost_element.percent}}"/>%</td><td><input class="btn_minus btn btn-danger" name="btn_minus' + n + '" type="button" value="X"/></td></tr>');
    });

    $('table').on('click', ".btn_minus", function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('name');
      $('tr[id="' + id + '"]').remove();
    });

    $('.btn_delete').click(function() {
      location.href = "";
    });


    $('table').on('change', '.usd_value', function() {
      alert('work!');
      $('#id_pesos_value').val() = $('#id_usd_value').val() * $('#percent').val(); 
      // in this last line you have wrong the assignment and you can't refer to ID
      //     change with class like ".id_usd_value" etc...
    });

  });
  //}); <-- this is too much !

</script>
```

[This is your code corrected on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpp005z5/7/)

Comment: Thanks, but still not working.....i updated the code upside so you can see and help me please, what could possibily be wrong ?? im sure it's well identaded

Comment: @jsanchezs Check the updated jsfiddle... obviously I changed some parts to make them more readable. I do not think you will be hard to correct them.

Comment: @jsanchezs It was a pleasure to help you :)